# map function with previous and next list element in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I have a list e.g. `[1,2,3,4,5]` where I need to know not only the current element but also the predecessor and successor elements. Is there any map function which can be used as follows:

```hs
map (\prev cur next -> ...) [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Or maybe you have another idea to solve the problem?

Comment: what do you want to accomplish? give us a set of input and output desired

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `tails` and then process each three items:

```
import Data.List(tails)

[ … | (x₀ : x₁ : x₂ : _) <- tails [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] ]
```

for example:

```
import Data.List(tails)

[ (x₀, x₁, x₂) | (x₀ : x₁ : x₂ : _) <- tails [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] ]
```

Here the `(x₀, x₁, x₂)` parameters will thus work with `(1, 2, 3)`, `(2, 3, 4)` and `(3, 4, 5)`.

Comment: `tails` is a very nice solution

Answer (score 4):

You can zip the lists together and drop one element of each

```
>> as = [1..5]
>> zipWith3 (\prev cur next -> (prev, cur, next)) as (drop 1 as) (drop 2 as)
[(1,2,3),(2,3,4),(3,4,5)]
```